# problem in store mouse click coordinates to an array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a simple problem , that I could not solve it after 3 days , then any help is welcomed

I have a picturebox in C# , I want Click on image in 4 different places , and I need store coordinates of these 4 points clicked in an array

i have this code

```
    private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
   ...
    }
```

and i want to click on image 4 times (for example with this coordinates (10,35)(30,55)(60,150)(80,140))
with e.X and e.Y i could only store one point! i need 4 different point
and i dont know what code must to write that with coordinates store in an array like this:

```
double[] A = new double[]{ 10,35)(30,55)(60,150)(80,140)};
```

thanks in advance! I searched 3days but i could not solve it

Comment: can you show the code that only gets you one coordinate?

Comment: Instead of array i would suggest you to create a class named MouseCordinates with two parameters X and Y pos.Then create a list of that class.when the list.count >= 4 then stop taking inputs and iterate over list and simply get the values.

Comment: Some things to consider - 1) a coordinate has two numbers, a double represents one number, so you can not use that as your array type (hint: look at tuples). 2) each click is a separate event, meaning the MouseDown method will get called for each click. Your array needs to last longer than that, so you need to store it outside of the method

Answer (score 2):

You could do this by adding a `List<Point>` field to the class, and adding a point to it each time `pictureBox1_MouseDown()` is called.

Then when there are 4 items in the list, do something with the 4 points stored in it, and then clear it ready for the next 4 points.

For example:

```
List<Point> _points = new List<Point>(); // List field to store points.

private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    _points.Add(e.Location);

    if (_points.Count == 4)
    {
        // Do something with _points.
        MessageBox.Show("4 locations clicked: \r\n" + string.Join(", ", _points));

        _points.Clear(); // Empty the array ready for the next 4 points.
    }
}
```

You would replace the `MessageBox.Show()` with whatever you need to do to process the 4 points.